# Gradle build failing in Unity 2022.2.7f1 after the implementation of Unity Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

When I try to patch and run to my device, I keep getting an error saying "Gradle build failed". It seems like the errors are coming after I implemented Unity Ads.
The error describes that this went wrong:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnableI checked the console and here are the details:

I check the console and here are the details.

> Failed to deploy application to device "SBXDU19329006259 [MAR-LX1M].
> Detailed log:
> stdout:
> stderr:
> [pram:00.000][v  ] Successfully parsed commandline: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.2.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\Pram\pram.dll" "--provider-load-path=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.2.7f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/Pram.Platform.Android" --verbose app-deploy --environment SBXDU19329006259 Android com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle"
> [pram:00.004][v  ] app-deploy Android com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle
> [pram:00.005][v  ] Lookup provider with query string Android
> [pram:00.006][v  ] Scan assemblies
> [pram:00.034][v  ] Created android provider
> [pram:00.036][v  ] Used environment variables and current values:
> [pram:00.036][v  ]           ANDROID_HOME: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.2.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK
> [pram:00.036][v  ]       ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: 
> [pram:00.036][v  ]              JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.2.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
> [pram:00.036][v  ]         ANDROID_SERIAL: 
> [pram:00.036][v  ]         PRAM_DIRECTORY: Library/PramData
> [pram:00.037][v  ] Lookup environment & application controller with environmentIdDescriptor "SBXDU19329006259"  architecture "" and applicationId "com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner"
> [pram:00.051][v  ] Acquiring deployment lock file
> [pram:00.070][v  ] Resolving executable for ADBCommandLineTool
> [pram:00.076][v  ] "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.2.7f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe" start-server (daemon)
> [pram:00.077][v  ] "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.2.7f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe" start-server (detach)
> [pram:00.096][v  ] Waiting to get exit code
> [pram:00.182][v  ] Executing: "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.2.7f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe" -s SBXDU19329006259 shell  "getprop ro.build.version.release"
> [pram:00.339][inf] Shadow Files Enabled Paths:
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/assets/bin/Data
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/lib_burst_generated.so
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libMonoPosixHelper.so
> [pram:00.339][inf]  * unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libmono-native.so
> [pram:00.369][v  ] Sync gradle project
> [pram:00.505][inf] 2 Gradle project files out of sync
> [pram:00.509][inf] APK out of sync
> [pram:00.509][inf] Build and deploy Gradle project
> [pram:00.522][v  ] "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/3PjIrPfuuRb_wie6/gradlew.bat" --quiet --daemon -p "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/AndroidApplicationController/Cache/com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner/gradle-project" (daemon)
> [pram:00.522][v  ] "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/3PjIrPfuuRb_wie6/gradlew.bat" --quiet --daemon -p "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/AndroidApplicationController/Cache/com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner/gradle-project" (detach)
> [pram:00.531][v  ] Waiting to get exit code
> [pram:19.281][v  ] Executing: "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/3PjIrPfuuRb_wie6/gradlew.bat" -p "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/AndroidApplicationController/Cache/com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner/gradle-project" installDebug
> [pram:29.388][err] '"C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/3PjIrPfuuRb_wie6/gradlew.bat" -p "C:/Users/japhe/Unity projects/Square/Library/PramData/AndroidApplicationController/Cache/com.devsbyjaphethhirpa.endlesssquarerunner/gradle-project" installDebug' returned with exit code 1.
> [pram:29.389][err] Err:
> [pram:29.389][err]
> [pram:29.389][err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> [pram:29.389][err]
> [pram:29.389][err] * What went wrong:
> [pram:29.389][err] Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> [pram:29.389][err] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> [pram:29.389][err]    > Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsInitializationListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsLoadListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsShowListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsTokenListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$1 found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsInitializationError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsLoadError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsShowCompletionState found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsShowError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAdsBaseOptions found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAdsLoadOptions found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAdsShowOptions found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.InAppPurchaseMetaData found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MediationMetaData found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MetaData found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.PlayerMetaData found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.DispatchGroup found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.GMAAdsError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.GMAEvent found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IAdsErrorHandler found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IScarAdListenerWrapper found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IScarAdapter found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IScarInterstitialAdListenerWrapper found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IScarRewardedAdListenerWrapper found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.IUnityAdsError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.R found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.ScarAdapterBase found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.ScarAdapterBase$1 found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.Utils found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.WebViewAdsError found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.scarads.IScarAd found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.scarads.IScarLoadListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.scarads.ScarAdMetadata found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.common.signals.ISignalCollectionListener found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$attr found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$color found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$dimen found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$drawable found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$id found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$integer found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$layout found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$string found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$style found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.R$styleable found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.ScarAdapter found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1:)
> [pram:29.389][err]      Duplicate class com.unity3d.scar.adapter.v1920.ScarAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-UnityAds-runtime (:UnityAds:) and jetified-com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.6.1-runtime (:com.unity3d.ads.unit

I tried to change the Gradle properties file but as far as I know it doesn't include the enable r8 line. I also tried changing my Scripting Backed from Mono to IL2CPP but nothing seems to work. My Keystore Password is also typed in right by the way.